# ¿Cómo eliminar registros repetidos de una consulta en sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Buen día, tengo una tabla donde existen registros repetidos pero con un id diferente, es decir que los valores de las otras columnas de mi table se llegan a repetir los datos por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el que no se debe repetir?

Comment: Pues en ese caso se repite el registro con id: 20334 y 36506, no importa cual se quita de la consulta, con que solo me regreso uno la consulta esta bien.

Comment: que consultas intentaste hasta ahora que no funcionaron?

Comment: a lo que me refiero es, ¿cuál es la columna de la tabla que se toma como referencia para la repeticion? Nombre, CURP, RFC

Comment: para evitar eso a futuro, considera hacer algún campo de esos `unique` para evitar registros duplicados :)

Comment: @gbianchi he intentado esto, pero faltan muchos registros, es decir que casi se acerca a lo que espero obtener pero mucho registros no se recuperan.

select id_movimiento, Nombre, CURP, RFC 
from SAT.Movimientos 
where CURP in (select CURP from SAT.Movimientos group by CURP, RFC, Nombre having count(CURP)=1)

Comment: usa el boton [edit] para agregar lo que intentaste hasta ahora y no funciono.

Comment: Probaste con un distinct? o esa es la solucion que estas buscando?

Comment: @gbianchi, si probé con un distinct pero no me daba los resultados esperados.

Comment: ok. Agrega todos los querys que probaste, los resultados que obtuviste y que esperabas obtener. Porque para mi un distinct es tu solucion...

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Nombre, CURP, RFC ORDER BY id_movimiento)
    FROM dbo.TuTabla
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

recuerda que siempre para sacar valores únicos las mejores practicas indican que tienes que hacer un group by (agrupar) en este caso se debería utilizar de la siguiente manera:

```
select *
from tabla;

/*  datos repetidos */
select max(id_movimiento), Nombre, CURP, RFC
from tabla
group by Nombre, CURP, RFC
having count(id_movimiento) > 1;

/*  borrado de ids  */
delete tabla
where id_movimiento in (
select max(id_movimiento)
from tabla d
group by Nombre, CURP, RFC
having count(id_movimiento) > 1);

/*  todos los datos */
select *
from tabla;
```